# Autofilter does not display existing data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using VBA to autofilter a large list. (Just under 5,000 rows). Specifically, I am searching for a vendor in an expense log. When I run this code, it finds many vendors just fine, but not others.

```
Private Function testMcTesterson()
Dim icell As Range
Dim tempStr As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim w As Workbook
Dim expLog As Workbook
Dim vendorName As String

Set expLog = Workbooks("FY18 Manual Expense Log.xlsm")
Set w = ActiveWorkbook

For Each icell In Selection
    vendorName = VendorNormalizer(icell.Value)

    expLog.Activate

    'Filter by vendor
    Debug.Print "Vendor name is " & "'" & vendorName & "'"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=vendorName

    w.Activate
Next icell

End Function
```

I am calling another function I have built to normalize the names of the vendors. Several are not working (and several are), but the one I am wrestling with at the moment is Amazon. We have several transactions from Amazon, but none show.

Things I have checked so far:

- Type the vendor's name into the autofilter. This produces results, so it is not the case that rows are excluded from the filter.
- Check which columns are autofiltered. Only the vendor column, so the code is not applying the filter to the wrong column. (Also because it works for other vendors)
- I was suspecting the problem may be with the output of my normalizing function, so I inserted my debug.print statement. Immediately before the filter is run, the console reads "Vendor name is 'Amazon'" No spaces before or after. I copied that directly from my immediate window, in case I just spelled something wrong.
- I even checked typename(vendorName) and it returns string.

I'm sure the solution is right in front of my face, I just can't see it.

Help!

Edit: Here is the pertinent code for VendorNormalizer

```
Private Function VendorNormalizer(vendorName As String)

Select Case True
    'Lots of other cases

    Case InStr(1, vendorName, "Amazon", vbTextCompare) > 0
        VendorNormalizer = "Amazon"

    'Lots of other cases
End select

'If statements for exact matches

End function
```

The spreadsheet I am searching has all of these (and no other Amazon entries) in the column I am filtering. (copied and pasted)

- AMAZON.COM
- Amazon marketplace
- Amazon.com
- AMAZON MKTPLACE PMTS

Comment: I'd add the code for `VendorNormalizer` to your question, otherwise we can't tell what it's doing exactly (i.e. what "Amazon" looks like pre-normalization and how it's normalized).

Comment: Maybe some mock data showing the problem would be helpful too

Comment: Instead of the autofilter, I'd suggest instead you use the Advanced Filter functionality, and pad your terms with wildcards. That would do away with the normalizer routine altogether.

Comment: Does it change anything when you change `Case InStr(1, vendorName, "Amazon", vbTextCompare)` to `Case InStr(vendorName, "Amazon")`?

Comment: Totsie: That would make the InStr search case sensitive. I don't want that.
Jeffrey: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need the normalizer routine. It accomplishes other normalizing than searching with wildcards would accomplish (though not in this case.)

Comment: Ah...it acts like what I call an Alias table. I do something similar with dictionaries in one of my routines.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to TotsieMae for having the breakthrough suggestion. Turns out wildcards are the answer.

Apparently the VBA range.autofilter command requires the criteria be an exact match, though typing into the autofilter does not. The solution is as simple as including wildcards in the text output of the normalizer.

To:

```
Select Case True
    'Lots of other cases

    Case InStr(1, vendorName, "Amazon", vbTextCompare) > 0
        VendorNormalizer = "*Amazon*"

    'Lots of other cases
End select
```

Thank you all for your help!